# Getting 401 when WCF OperationInvoker calls another WCF service

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-401, servicebehavior

We have an attribute called `LoggingImplementationBehavior` that causes a WCF Logging service to get called before and after service calls it's attached to.

This works great both locally and on the shared development server. However, on the staging server a 401 error is returned when a call is made to the Logging service from the invoker. To ensure that the issue is not in the Logging service I commented all code out so that it does nothing, but I still get this error when the stub is called.

In IIS Manager, Anonymous Authentication is enabled (and nothing else) at both the server level and at the services website level. Digest Authentication is disabled at both levels, so what could be the cause of these 401 errors?

I've seen others have this problem with large data but the data being sent here is quite small.

Any tips on how to continue debugging this problem would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently at a dead end.

The exact text of the error is:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Digest qop="auth",algorithm=MD5-sess,nonce="+Upgraded+v171b25f8f2632897bff13b10710dac91aa1d64068a3cccf011b44f8580e932354dfd50d56778ba404d674864cf9d5216e589c616fb1a48583",charset=utf-8,realm="Digest"'.
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop.aspx

Comment: @Aron Thanks, but I'm a little confused by your response. If I'm using only Anonymous Authentication then why would anything related to kerberos matter? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Oh...I didn't see the part about Anonymous Auth. It is possible that there is code in your `LoggingImplementationBehavior` that requires you are logged in (to log the user)...

Comment: @Aron I wrote the code so I can confidently say that there's not anything that requires you to be logged in. It just collects some information like the time, method that called, and parameter values and then makes a call to the Logging service. I've stepped through this code and when the call to the service is made is when the error occurs. (Likewise, I wrote the Logging service and there's nothing in there but some code to write to file, but the 401 error occurs before any of this code is actually reached).